# Logarithmic list range construction

Tags: python, math, logarithm

I have some code to create a list of list number ranges. However what I want is the list to have a decreasing range as the numbers get higher. This is my current linear growth list.

```
>>> a = []
>>> for i in xrange(0,100,5):
    a.append([i,i+5])   
>>> a
[[0, 5], [5, 10], [10, 15], [15, 20], [20, 25], [25, 30], [30, 35], [35, 40], [40, 45], [45, 50], [50, 55], [55, 60], [60, 65], [65, 70], [70, 75], [75, 80], [80, 85], [85, 90], [90, 95], [95, 100]]
```

I would like a list that has a decreasing growth rate, like a Logarithmic function. I am unsure how to achieve this using python. The numbers at the end of one list must be equal to the start of the next and numbers can only be integers. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable length of the ranges:

```
a = []
length = 20
current = 0
maximum = 100
factor = 1.3
while current < maximum:
    new = min(maximum, current + length)
    a.append([current, new])
    current = new
    length = int(max(length / factor, 1))
```

Adjust `length` (initial range length) and `factor` (decrease for each range) to your needs.

Example output:

```
[[0, 20], [20, 35], [35, 46], [46, 54], [54, 60], [60, 64], [64, 67], [67, 69], [69, 70], [70, 71], [71, 72], [72, 73], [73, 74], [74, 75], [75, 76], [76, 77], [77, 78], [78, 79], [79, 80], [80, 81], [81, 82], [82, 83], [83, 84], [84, 85], [85, 86], [86, 87], [87, 88], [88, 89], [89, 90], [90, 91], [91, 92], [92, 93], [93, 94], [94, 95], [95, 96], [96, 97], [97, 98], [98, 99], [99, 100]]
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I have to make my factor really small as the range between current and maximum get larger (>10000). Is there a way of reducing the sensitivity of factor?

Comment: @user3818749 You could of course just decrease it to whatever you need, for example, `1.3 ** 0.25` will give you `[[0, 20], [20, 38], [38, 54], [54, 68], [68, 81], [81, 93], [93, 100]]` (it decreases only `1/4` as fast)